# Bot Framework Typing indicator is not working in new MS Team ( Work or School )

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

The typing indicator feature in the bot framework is not being detected by the new Microsoft Teams ( Work or School ) application, and it seems to be functioning properly only in the older version of Microsoft Teams Classic.

`Bot Framework SDK version is 4.18.1`.

The implementation for the typing indicator does not involve any custom code, and instead, we are utilizing the default typing indicator middleware (`ShowTypingMiddleware`) that comes with the Bot Framework SDK. This middleware is integrated into the `AdapterWithErrorHandler` and it inherits `CloudAdapter`.

Also reported the same issue on various forums, but there has been no adequate response or resolution, and it is hoped that a proper fix will be implemented.

[Typing indicator issue](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/a850c116-529a-ee11-a81c-000d3a02ba69)

Comment: We are able to repro this issue. We have raised a bug for this, and engineering team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also seeing this.

Comment: Apologies. Currently there is no update to share. We are following up with engineering team about this issue. We will update this thread once we hear from them. Thanks!

Comment: The comment here https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/9700#issuecomment-1942963950 states it was purposefully disabled due to some outage. That is unacceptable.