# TeamsBot SendActivityAsync with ActivityTypes.Typing no longer works

Tags: c#, bots, microsoft-teams

We've been using a Teams Bot to send back a typing reply in `OnMessageActivityAsync`. It worked until recently, doing it in this manner

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(new Activity { Type = ActivityTypes.Typing }, cancellationToken);
}
```

As of recently, in new Teams, this no longer works. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: We already have a bug for this, and engineering team is looking into it. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue at the moment - see also this question from 2 weeks ago: [Bot Framework Typing indicator is not working in new MS Team ( Work or School )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77878531/bot-framework-typing-indicator-is-not-working-in-new-ms-team-work-or-school) . I'm seeing it my side as well.

Comment: Ahh...thank you. I somehow missed that one. I will close this one, once I can.