# Teams bot timeout

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have created a Teams bot in development. It is designed to call a REST API. What I have noticed is that if the API takes longer than about 30 seconds to respond the "operation cancelled" exception is thrown. I found in Bot Framework documentation that bots have to respond with a HTTP 200 code in 15 seconds.

How do, I work around this 15 seconds limit for Teams bots?

This code works fine if the REST API responds quickly but if it takes close to 30 seconds, I get the operation cancelled exception.

```
        public async Task<ICommandResponse> HandleCommandAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CommandMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://RESTENDPOINT/"
            var dataText = message.Text;

            Message msg = new Message() { role = "user", content = message.Text };
            ChatParams chatParams = new ChatParams() { model = "gpt-4-1106-preview", temperature = 0.3f, messages = new List<Message>() { msg }, stream = false };
            RequestBody requestBodyObject = new RequestBody() { chat_params = chatParams, conversation_id = 1, assistant_id = 1, uuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };


            var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBodyObject);


            var content = new StringContent(requestBody, null, "application/json");
            request.Content = content;
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            ChatCompletion chatCompletion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatCompletion>(responseText);

            var responseContent = chatCompletion.choices[0]?.message.content;

            _logger.LogInformation(responseContent);

            return new TextCommandResponse(responseContent);


        }
```

Comment: You should show your code so someone can even begin to figure out where the problem is for this.  I did a little digging but won't be typing up an answer on this, but can get you in the right direction, look into "proactive messaging" and get ready to do some C#.

Comment: I just used the sample generated by VS 2022 for Chat Command Bot and added a REST API call to it.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: I have added, hope that helps.

Comment: Also struggling with this. Answers from an LLM can take over 15 secinds easily. THat is a problem because your bot needs to let the turn end within 15 seconds or the Connector service will time out. As a result, streaming the answer will also not solve this. Using directline and webchat myself.

I looked into various options but did nog find a feasible solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

A few tips on this:

1. You can send a "Typing" activity to the user, to show them something is happening (it shows three little animated dots) - I think this might even give you more than 30 seconds, as the *first* response is within 30 seconds. See more  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#send-a-typing-indicator). Importantly, the -actual- animation isn't working in the "new" Teams at the moment - see [Bot Framework Typing indicator is not working in new MS Team ( Work or School )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77878531/bot-framework-typing-indicator-is-not-working-in-new-ms-team-work-or-school)
2. Rather than call the OpenAI endpoint directly, you can use one of the various SDKs, it makes the coding easier. Interesting, Microsoft's SDK supports both *Azure* Open AI as well as calls directly to Open AI's endpoint - see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.AI.OpenAI/
3. *Generally*, you'll actually find that an *Azure* Open AI instance responds *much* faster than a call directly to Open AI's endpoint (Azure Open AI is the same model, but hosted in Azure infrastructure and faster for a few possible reasons). *However*, the `gpt-4-1106-preview` model, presumably because it's a "preview", is -really- slow. It will probably speed up once it reaches GA.

Comment: It looks like Typing indicator is broken as you mentioned. Is there another alternative to indicate to Teams that Bot is active? As for Open AI we have custom REST APIs to access it and I am using those.

Comment: This will not  help because the bot  needs to end the turn within 15 seconds.

Comment: I'm not *100%* sure, but I think responding with the Typing Activity *itself* within 15 seconds is sufficient. I'm implemeting a RAG based bot at the moment and also seeing *very* variable response times, but it's working fine with the typing indicator.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can check the bot status and get to know whether it is active or like
[image]

The bug is also raised for typing indicator and we are actively checking the status with engineering team.

Comment: I noticed the other day, fyi, that if I move to another conversion, then in the chats list, the bot shows a typing indicator. It just doesn't appear in the chat itself, in case that helps.